# Postgresql with recursive query

Tags: postgresql

After trying with with recursion I have question

I am trying with two table

first table is `complain_table`

```
complain                   product_id
----------------------------------------
Not working          -          1
not working                     1
not working                     1
Loading problem                 2
Loading problem                 2
```

second table `product_table`

```
Name     id                      
--------------
usb      1
cd       2
```

Now my desired output is

```
product                complain
-----------------------------------
usb                   Not working
                      Not working
                      Not working
cd                    Loading problem
                      Loading problem
```

Comment: What did you already try? PostgreSQL version? How is this different to http://stackoverflow.com/q/19872751/398670 ? Did you follow the advice given there? **Format your questions please**. This doesn't require recursion at all, it should just be a `GROUP BY` and some `string_agg` use.

Comment: select p.product from
((with cte(product,sort, sort2,id) as (
    select distinct
        pp.name,pp.name,0,count(pp.name)
    from product_complaints pc 
    left join product_product pp on pp.id = pc.complaints_id
    group by pp.name,pc.complaints_id
    union all
    select
        '            ' || pc.name,pp.name,1,pc.product_id
    from product_complaints pc
    left join product_product pp on pp.id = pc.complaints_id
    group by pp.name,pc.product_id,pc.name
    )
select product,sort,sort2,id 
from cte
group by product,sort,sort2,id
order by  sort,sort2,id)) as p

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output as shown (suppressing the repeating product names), the following should do it:

```
select case 
         when row_number() over (partition by p.name order by ct.complain) = 1 then p.name
         else null
       end as product,
       ct.complain
from products p
  join complain_table ct on p.product_id = ct.product_id
order by p.product_id;
```

---

Btw: your `complain_table` looks like it should have a `complain_reason_id` referencing a `complain_reason_text` table to avoid repeating the same complain text over and over again